# How to fix out-of-place 'expected RBRACE' error when parsing CSS with jfx?

Tags: javafx, javafx-css

I was adding some variables to my CSS file, and I seem to have broken it. I have never used variables in CSS before (im not much of a front-end guy), so I dont know, if I did something wrong or the parser is acting up, because the error I'm getting seems non-sensical in consideration of where it occurs:

```
Mar 26, 2023 11:16:27 PM javafx.css.CssParser parse
WARNING: CSS Error parsing jar:file:///D:/Projects/jfxtest3/build/libs/jfxtest3-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/example/jfxtest3/main.css: Expected RBRACE at [4,4]
```

Here is the code that caused this:

```
:root
{
    --rosewatercol: #f5e0dc;
    --flamingocol: #f2cdcd; <-- according to the error, there should be a closed bracket at pos 4 in this line
    --pinkcol: #f5c2e7;
    --mauvecol: #cba6f7;
    --redcol: #f38ba8;
    --marooncol: #eba0ac;
    --peachcol: #fab387;
    --yellowcol: #f9e2af;
    --greencol: #a6e3a1;
    --tealcol: #94e2d5;
    --skycol: #89dceb;
    --sapphirecol: #74c7ec;
    --bluecol: #89b4fa;
    --lavendercol: #b4befe;
    --accentcol: --tealcol;
    --textcol: #cdd6f4;
    --subtext1col: #bac2de;
    --subtext0col: #a6adc8;
    --overlay2col: #9399b2;
    --overlay1col: #7f849c;
    --overlay0col: #6c7086;
    --surface2col: #585b70;
    --surface1col: #45475a;
    --surface0col: #313244;
    --basecol: #1e1e2e;
    --mantlecol: #181825;
    --crustcol: #11111b;
}

.root
{
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(from 0% 0% to 100% 100%, #181825, #1e1e2e);
    -fx-border-style: none;
    -fx-border-width: 0;
    -fx-border-insets: 0;
}

.root *
{
    -fx-font-size: 18;
    -fx-text-fill: --textcol;
    -fx-fill: --textcol;
    -fx-border-style: none;
    -fx-border-width: 0;
    -fx-border-insets: 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 12;
}

.button
{
    -fx-background-color: --surface0col;
    -fx-font-size: 18;
    -fx-text-fill: --textcol;
    -fx-fill: --textcol;
}

.button:hover
{
    -fx-background-color: --surface1col;
}

.vbox
{
    -fx-background-color: --surface0col;
}

.hbox
{
    -fx-background-color: --surface0col;
}

.accordion
{
    -fx-background-color: --surface0col;
}

.titled-pane > .title
{
    -fx-background-color: --surface0col;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-border-style: none;
    -fx-border-width: 0;
    -fx-border-insets: 0;
}

.titled-pane > .title > *.text
{
    -fx-fill: #fff;
}

.titled-pane > .content
{
    -fx-background-color: --surface0col;
    -fx-border-style: none;
    -fx-border-width: 0;
    -fx-border-insets: 0;
}
```

What did I do wrong and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

I've found the answer.
JavaFX doesn't actually support variables, only non-standard looked-up colors.
They only start with one hyphen, and doesn't live in :root, but .root.
And as the name implies, they only work for colors, nothing else.

Here is the code from above changed to work with looked-up colors:

```
.root
{
    -rosewatercol: rgb(245, 224, 220);
    -flamingocol: rgb(242, 205, 205);
    -pinkcol: #f5c2e7;
    -mauvecol: #cba6f7;
    -redcol: #f38ba8;
    -marooncol: #eba0ac;
    -peachcol: #fab387;
    -yellowcol: #f9e2af;
    -greencol: #a6e3a1;
    -tealcol: #94e2d5;
    -skycol: #89dceb;
    -sapphirecol: #74c7ec;
    -bluecol: #89b4fa;
    -lavendercol: #b4befe;
    -accentcol: -tealcol;
    -textcol: #cdd6f4;
    -subtext1col: #bac2de;
    -subtext0col: #a6adc8;
    -overlay2col: #9399b2;
    -overlay1col: #7f849c;
    -overlay0col: #6c7086;
    -surface2col: #585b70;
    -surface1col: #45475a;
    -surface0col: #313244;
    -basecol: #1e1e2e;
    -mantlecol: #181825;
    -crustcol: #11111b;
}

.root
{
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(from 0% 0% to 100% 100%, #181825, #1e1e2e);
    -fx-border-style: none;
    -fx-border-width: 0;
    -fx-border-insets: 0;
}

.root *
{
    -fx-font-size: 18;
    -fx-text-fill: -textcol;
    -fx-fill: -textcol;
    -fx-border-style: none;
    -fx-border-width: 0;
    -fx-border-insets: 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 12;
}

.button
{
    -fx-background-color: -surface0col;
    -fx-font-size: 18;
    -fx-text-fill: -textcol;
    -fx-fill: -textcol;
}

.button:hover
{
    -fx-background-color: -surface1col;
}

.vbox
{
    -fx-background-color: -surface0col;
}

.hbox
{
    -fx-background-color: -surface0col;
}

.accordion
{
    -fx-background-color: -surface0col;
}

.titled-pane > .title
{
    -fx-background-color: -surface0col;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-border-style: none;
    -fx-border-width: 0;
    -fx-border-insets: 0;
}

.titled-pane > .title > *.text
{
    -fx-fill: #fff;
}

.titled-pane > .content
{
    -fx-background-color: -surface0col;
    -fx-border-style: none;
    -fx-border-width: 0;
    -fx-border-insets: 0;
}
```